# How to increment two counters in a synchronized way on two different components?

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I have a page that displays a number of images as well as a counter that displays the total number of likes of all images

```
const ImagesPage = () => { 
    //Get data
    const images = [{id: 1, image: "image1.jpg", likes: 62},{id: 2, image: "image2.jpg", likes: 35},{id: 3, image: "image3.jpg", likes: 45}];

    //Get total of likes
    const getTotalLikes = () => {
        let totalLikes = 0
        images.forEach(image => (likesList+=image.likes))
        return totalLikes
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Images
            data={images}
            />
            <Counter
            totalLikes={getTotalLikes()}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

On each image I have a button which increments the number of likes of a photo

```
const Images = ({data}) => { 

    const [count, setCount] = useState()
    const handleIncrement = () => {
            setCount(prevCount => prevCount+1);
        };

        return (
            {data.map(elt=>(
            <img key={elt.id} src={elt.image} alt={elt.id}/>
            <button onClick={handleIncrement}>{count}</button>))
            }
        )
}
```

How can I make sure to increment my total like counter at the same time as I increment the one of the image ?

Comment: You need to lift the state up and let the parent have a shared state for both of your image components. https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper

Comment: You can pass along the index and a call back function to increment likes based on index from images page componet to the each images component. When ever like for a particular image is clicked, you can call the callback and update the like counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoist both the data and the implementation details of updating the data to the parent. That way, when the data is updated both the `ImagesPage` and `Images` components will re-render with the new values.

```
// or this could be given to ImagesPage through props
const data = [
  { id: 1, image: "image1.jpg", likes: 62 },
  { id: 2, image: "image2.jpg", likes: 35 },
  { id: 3, image: "image3.jpg", likes: 45 }
];

const ImagesPage = () => { 
  const [images, setImages] = useState(data);

  // total likes
  const totalLikes = images.reduce((total, image) => total + image.likes, 0);

  // handle updating the like count. This function is given to `Images`
  const handleLikeImage = (id) => () => {
    const newData = images.map((image) => {
      if (image.id === id) {
        image.likes += 1;
      }

      return image;
    })
      
    setImages(newData);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Images data={images} onLike={handleLikeImage} />
      <Counter totalLikes={totalLikes} />
    </div>
  )
}

const Images = ({ data, onLike }) => {
  return data.map((image) => (
    <React.Fragment key={image.id}>
      <img src={image.image} alt={image.id} />
      {/* call the onLike method, passing in id */}
      <button onClick={onLike(id)}>{image.likes}</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  ));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand better the principle of lift up the state